# NodeJS MongoDB ReplicaSetNoPrimary

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was attempting to connect to a MongoDB cluster using the following from the **nodeJS** **MongoDB** package

```
const client = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const conn = await client.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_DSN,
  {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    ssl: process.env.MONGO_SSL, // true
  },
)
```

The `MONGO_DSN` variable is as follows:

```
mongodb://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST1}:27017,{HOST2}:27017,{HOST3}:27017/{DB_NAME}?ssl=true&replicaSet={REPLICASET}&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

However, the connection times out with the error

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to {IP_ADDRESS}:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  name: 'MongoServerSelectionError',
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      '{HOST1}:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      '{HOST2}:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      '{HOST3}:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

After a little playing around, I found out that I can connect successfully if I remove the `ssl` config option from the driver constructor and leave it to infer it from the DSN query string:

```
const client = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const conn = await client.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_DSN,
  {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
)
```

Why would this config option (not sure if others effect this too) effect the ability to connect?

Is it because if there are config options specified in the constructor that appear in the DSN, then it completely ignores the DSN query string, which would mean some config options would then be missing (primary replica)?

To clarify, there are no issues with the hosts in the DSN, no issues with connecting to the database normally, only when the config is set in the constructor.

Comment: Your deployment does not support tls and you are trying to force tls?

Comment: No? I'm using SSL. There's no mention of TLS in the question.

Comment: SSL are deprecated aliases for TLS. The underlying protocol is TLS.

Comment: I see, so when I add `ssl: true` to the driver config, it's trying to use TLS?

Comment: What does the driver documentation say?

Comment: Just says that it's deprecated and I should use the TLS variants, not that I can't use SSL or that the ssl config will use TLS and not that it's an alias for TLS

Comment: > Use ssl connection deprecated use tls variants

Comment: Right. The language should probably use TLS instead of SSL. In any event, you were trying to request ssl, the server presumably wasn't configured for either ssl or tls (you can request ssl but you'd get tls regardless), hence your connection wasn't working.

Comment: The server is configured for SSL. I mentioned in the question that if I remove the SSL config option from the driver and just have it in the DSN then everything works fine and I can connect.

Comment: Sounds like the server isn't configured as you think it is.

Comment: Use mongo shell to verify connectivity and inspect server log for TLS bits.